# Drupal aggregate css crashes IE7

Tags: 7, theming, performance

If I turn on aggregate css in my performance config and then load my site in IE7, the browser crashes.   Any ideas why that might be?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Can you expound upon "the browser crashes"? Does the application literally stop responding, or is the web page just rendered incorrectly? Are there any error messages in your logs (Drupal, PHP, apache, etc.)?

Comment: Browser crashes means IE7 closes and there is a dialog saying "Internet Explorer has a problem and needs to close"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a size limit of 300kb per file and a limit of 32 files.

http://joshua.perina.com/africa/gambia/fajara/post/internet-explorer-css-file-size-limit

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/ad1b6e88-bbfa-4cc4-9e95-3889b82a7c1d

Comment: question is about when aggregate is on...

Comment: Thanks for the links, I wasn't aware of the 300kb size limit in Explorer which was the problem